GCP not-secrets manager
Handling secrets within GCP is easy, Secrets Manager.
We, like probably many many others, generate secret values (terraform mostly for us) and store them in GCP Secrets Manager for consumption by other things (kubernetes, for example).
However what about not secret values? The same process as with secrets works perfectly well naturally, values are just values after all, but, the values are never exposed because they're secrets.
There are cases where we want values generated by terraform workflows both exposed to kubernetes pods entirely byway of automation, and still exposed to people (who can't see actually secret values).
Is there a GCP "variable manager" product that I'm just not seeing?
Or perhaps a means to have external-secrets operator create configmaps instead of secrets? This one I highly doubt, the security issues of allowing someone without access to kubernetes or GCP secrets, access to GCP secrets by way of just asking ESO for them is too great to allow.

Non, there isn't config manager product. You can use secret manager for non secret, or customize on the fly the config map (in terraform, or before/after) before pushing it to GKE

there is no tool as such. But you can make a workaround, using a cloud storage bucket as a ‘variable manager’. Here you can store your variables in JSON or other plain text format.
Given the right permissions, for example from roles/storage.objectViewer, you can have read access from any service like kubernetes or a person.
Additionally, there is a solution from hashicorp called Vault https://www.vaultproject.io/ which is used to store secrets and also manager, if you want to take a look at it.
I hope it helps!
